# The Doors in the Hallway

Tags: knowledge, pattern, story

*On the phone, an acquaintance of yours sounds panicked*

I know it sounds crazy, but you gotta listen to me.

Earlier today I got assaulted by a group of robed people, and now I just woke up in the middle of what looks like a hallway, and I'm stuck there! I see doors left and right and I think "Oh, well, no harm in listening". And you wouldn't believe what I heard!

"I would like to solve the puzzle", is what I could hear on the other side of that door, and the next door in line just had grunts and cries of what seemed like pain. So I kept going, and the third door I saw was silent, so I opened it. And inside was a corpse! A man hung from the ceiling! What am I supposed to do when I see that?

You have to help me dude, I want to get out of here, I just want to get back to the real world. Opening more doors sounds risky, and I know you're super smart, so please help!

*You take a bit of time to think,* ***which door should your friend open?***

Comment: This seems very arbitrary. I assume [tag:pattern] serves to disambiguate possible solutions?

Comment: Ideally, the solution includes the total number of doors, the pattern tag is there to be paired with knowledge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hallway represents

> a deck of tarot cards, specifically the 22 cards that make up the [Major Arcana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_Arcana).
>
> The first door represents card X, Wheel of Fortune, because "I would like to solve the puzzle" is a phrase commonly heard on the game show of the same name.
>
> The next door is XI, Strength, which depicts a woman subduing a lion by clasping its jaws, which is the source of the grunts and cries of pain (?)
>
> The third door is XII, The Hanged Man, which represents, well, a hanged man.

So you advise your friend to open

> door number XXI which represents The World, and thus an escape from the hallway.

Comment: There's no real answer to the question, nor do you explain the process of solving. This is simply too low quality to be accepted, you only explain the gimmick.

Comment: While I would want to award the checkmark to you @SQLnoob, I can't. Thank you for the edit nonetheless!

Comment: No worries, I didn't want to post a separate answer since the other poster figured out the meaning, just figured I'd flesh out the details a bit.